# Google Chrome - Hide Google Ads in Developer Tools (Network tab, Console, etc)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, adsense

Is there any way from keeping Google Ads from polluting my developer console with its Network events and console messages?

I have some Google Ads in the page, but they are polluting all of my dev tools, making it a bit goofy. I'm hoping there is some way to blacklist things from not showing up in my Developer Tools.

Note: I'm not looking to block the ads themselves (i.e., AdBlock is not a solution I'm looking for to my problem).